# Change Records List text vtiger 6.4

Tags: vtiger

I have created a custom module and when I see the list view of that module I see "Records List" in the left hand side sidebar (please see the screenshot for the same) so I want to change this text to "Module Name List"

Please help

[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, I found the file and the line you mentioned below but if I change this Records List to Terms List so its applying to all my custom modules and obviously  I want different names for all my different custom modules. Please suggest a way to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the label in language file

Open YOUR_MODULE_NAME.php file. `\languages\en_us\YOUR_MODULE_NAME.php.php`

Change `'LBL_RECORDS_LIST' => 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME List'`

Reload cache. Done!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont see the 'LBL_RECORDS_LIST' => 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME List' in my language file. My language file is - <?php
$languageStrings = array (
'ModuleName' => ' ModuleName ',
'SINGLE_ ModuleName ' => ' ModuleName ',
'LBL_ ModuleName _INFORMATION' => ' ModuleName Information',
'LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION' => 'Custom Information',
);

?>

Comment: Try to search LBL_RECORDS_LIST in entire folder of your crm and let me know where you get this..

Comment: I tried searching LBL_RECORDS_LIST in entire crm folder but no results found. Can you please help me adding this in my current language file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Changing language file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktwg3.png)

You should see it in the language file, however, if it's not there just add the line yourself (just make sure you put the comma at the end). If you want to change it for all modules, edit the label in the languages/en_us/Vtiger.php (should be line 414 or close to it)